# Salesforce: get link from account connected to projects

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities

I have an object "Project" that has a lookup field "Account__c". In the Salesforce experience builder, I want to have a link in the Project Detail page to the connected Account.

Something like "Go back to your account".

But I tried various links like "https://*our webite*/s/account/{!recordId.Account__c}"
I know that this: "https://* our website"/s/project/{!recordId}" works so I feel that there is a solution to this. I hope someone can help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using standard detail page components and are looking to build a formula field to expose the linked Account URL?

`/s/account/{!Account__r.Id}` should do the trick as a relative URL.